# Keras error ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontró el proceso especificado

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hola recientemente me encuentro trabajando con Keras para clasificación de imagen, sin embargo, cuando corro el siguiente código me manda error. Espero puedan ayudarme

> import keras as ks
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Using TensorFlow backend.
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 import keras as ks
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py
>   in 
>         1 from **future** import absolute_import
>         2 
>   ----> 3 from . import utils
>         4 from . import activations
>         5 from . import applications
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py
>   in 
>         4 from . import data_utils
>         5 from . import io_utils
>   ----> 6 from . import conv_utils
>         7 
>         8 # Globally-importable utils.
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py
>   in 
>         7 from six.moves import range
>         8 import numpy as np
>   ----> 9 from .. import backend as K
>        10 
>        11
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py
>   in 
>        87 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
>        88     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
>   ---> 89     from .tensorflow_backend import *
>        90 else:
>        91     # Try and load external backend.
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py
>   in 
>         3 from **future** import print_function
>         4 
>   ----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
>         6 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as tf_ops
>         7 from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py
>   in 
>        22 
>        23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
>   ---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>        25 
>        26 try:
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py
>   in 
>        57 
>        58 # Protocol buffers
>   ---> 59 from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
>        60 from tensorflow.core.framework.node_def_pb2 import *
>        61 from tensorflow.core.framework.summary_pb2 import *
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py
>   in 
>         4 import sys
>         5 _b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
>   ----> 6 from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
>         7 from google.protobuf import message as _message
>         8 from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py
>   in 
>        45   import binascii
>        46   import os
>   ---> 47   from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
>        48   _USE_C_DESCRIPTORS = getattr(_message, '_USE_C_DESCRIPTORS', False)
>        49
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontró el proceso especificado.

Comment: A primera vista me parece que tienes una versión de la dll que no va de la mano con la versión que tienes de la biblioteca. Te sugiero que te asegures que tienes instaladas y haces referencia a las versiones correctas, es decir, que son compatibles entre si.

Comment: es un problema con la versión de python, para mi funciono pasar de python 3.6 a la 3.6.6